# UUID when we select database - performance test

Tags: mysql, sql, uuid

I have primary key UUID (in the number, not as a String).  String is very slow.

Is standard Integer primary key much more faster then UUID when I'm writing SQL SELECT? Do you have that tastes?

Comment: This depends on the query and how you have indexed related tables. Are you referencing the PK from another table as a foreign key? If so, is the relationship defined, which enforces an index on the related table?

Answer (score 1):

In principle yes, integer keys are always better because comparisons of equality or inequality can be done with a single machine instruction. However, for string fields, if equality is the only relevant operation, a hash table index can be used (which should also be fast). I haven't explore this option with the hash tables of mysql, have a look.